# How do I solve skewness in a percentage difference calculation?

Tags: skewness, computational-statistics

I have two variables I want to evaluate -- Planned Hours per project and Tracked Hours per project. Sometimes Planned Hours exceeds Tracked Hours, but often it's the reverse.

I calculated the percentage difference between Tracked Hours and Planned Hours as follows: `Percent Diff = (Tracked Hours - Planned Hours) / Planned Hours.` The resulting data ranges from -99% to 5,200%.

Obviously, that creates problems when I represent the data graphically and even when I compute a z-score to find outliers (i.e., heavy right skew and only outliers on the positive side of the distribution).

One option I thought of was computing the opposite operation `Percent Diff = (Planned Hours - Tracked Hours) / Tracked Hours.` Then I'd use this whenever Planned Hours exceeds Tracked Hours on a project and the first formula when Tracked Hours exceeds Planned Hours. I *believe* that solves the issue, but I'd love a sanity check on this idea and maybe some alternatives.

I am really rusty on stats after spending 7 years as a project manager. Anyone have a suggestion/solution?

Comment: I have clarifying question: Do you mean $\frac{\text{Tracked Hours} - \text{Planned Hours}}{\text{Planned Hours}}$ by `Tracked Hours - Planned Hours / Planned Hours`. I am just thinking about order of operations and what resembles calculations I have performed in a chemistry setting.

Comment: @Galen Yes, correct.

Comment: Could you create some plot of the data? And provide some insight into what is important?

Comment: You might want to look at [this blog post](https://www.fharrell.com/post/percent/) about why percent changes aren't such a good way to present findings. A plot of tracked hours versus planned hours(maybe on logarithmic scales) is probably most informative, both for us and for your audience.